# Dual Boot Windows 10 with Arch

Tags: windows-10, installation, multi-boot, arch-linux, dualboot

I am about to install Arch along side Windows 10 on my new gaming Desktop using a second m.2 NVME. (For work, and programming) However, I want to know what are some common traps that people have come across in doing what I am doing. (i.e. not properly choosing right boot paths and gub configs etc.)

I have installed Arch a number of times and have used arch mainly for years now, so I am quite comfortable with any answers or suggestions.

In short, what are some suggestions for installing Arch after installing Windows 10 on a different drive?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have a similar setup with Arch Linux and Windows 10. When you have them installed on separate drives, I wouldn't be to concerned about it. By the way if you want Windows to show up in the GRUB boot loader, I'd advice you to install `os-prober` on Arch Linux, it's a utility that detects other operating systems automatically and doesn't require any major configuration.

Comment: Hey Adam - this is a good question, but it's not a great fit for SuperUser. We go more for direct questions and answers here, and your question is one that could have a lot of discussion behind it instead of just having one good answer. Arch's forums would be a better place for it.